# Gnuplot: Box and Whisker Plot - Undefined Variable: Using

Tags: gnuplot, boxplot

I'm playing around with trying to create a Box and Whisker plot with gnuplot, to output into a latex document. I keep having the following error:

> "test.gp", line 10: undefined variable: using

My code is below:

```
set terminal latex
set output "test.tex"
set style data boxplot
set style fill solid 0.25 border -1
set style boxplot outliers pointtype 7

set datafile separator ","
set xrange[0:6] 
set yrange[0.000:1.000] 
plot "test.csv" using 1:3:2:6:5:xticlabels(7) with candlesticks notitle whiskerbars, using 1:4:4:4:4 with candlesticks lt -1 notitle
```

And here is the CSV file that I'm using:

> 1,0.381768,0.386109,0.423836,0.381768,0.42965,"0.3",
>   2,0.400131,0.446271,0.47671,0.400131,0.481733,"0.4",
>   3,0.442295,0.443961,0.512071,0.442295,0.58654,"0.5",
>   4,0.464072,0.502773,0.516437,0.464072,0.589175,"0.6",
>   5,0.460358,0.468294,0.479633,0.460358,0.562291,"0.7",

Is anybody able to help me figure out what's wrong

Comment: BTW are you interested in plotting the `candlesticks` or `boxplots`?

Comment: What's the difference? I've mainly been following examples I found online and they use candlesticks.

Comment: Well, with boxplots you just specify your column of data and the mean, stdev will be calculated. You also have the options to show outliers in different styles. Whereas with candlesticks you explicitly need to specify the five point summary i.e. min, 25%ile, median, 75%ile and max. So if you are just planning to get candlesticks, which is also evident from your data then `set style data boxplot` and `set style boxplot outliers pointtype 7` are not needed.

Comment: Also look at these links for examples: http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_canvas/boxplot.html and http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/candlesticks.html

Comment: Thanks, wish I knew that before I wrote the code to calculate it all, lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your plot command, you are missing the second `''`,Try this:

```
plot "test.csv" using 1:3:2:6:5:xticlabels(7) with candlesticks notitle whiskerbars, '' using 1:4:4:4:4 with candlesticks lt -1 notitle
```